# Could someone help prove some properties of Legendre Polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, mathematical-physics, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I have already proved other properties of the Legendre polynomials, like:

$$P_n(-x) = (-1)^n \, P_n(x)$$
$$P_{2n+1}(0) = 0$$
$$P_n(\pm1)= (\pm1)^n$$

But I can't get this one:

$$P_{2n}(0) = \frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}n((n-1)!)^2}$$

I'd be glad if someone can help me with this.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you define Legendre polynomials in the first place. If it's from $P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x^2 -1)^n$, you can do that by induction. If it's the generating function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x) t^n$, then develop the LHS in power series for $x=0$.

Comment: I've tried do it for this 2 ways but I don´t get the result, I don't know what is my mistake.

Comment: Post your attempts.

Comment: Another hint: with the first definition, to compute $P_{2n}(0)$ you need to find the constant term of the $2n$-th derivative of a polynomial of degree $4n$. That is, you have to find the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ of this polynomial. You don't even need induction.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't get how to develop the derivate $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^n$

Comment: But do you get how to develop $(x^2-1)^n$ and find the coefficient of $x^n$? (or rather, for your case as you have $P_{2n}$, develop $(x^2-1)^{2n}$ and get the coefficient of $x^{2n}$). That's like developing $(a+b)^n$ with binomial formula. Hence binomial coefficients and factorials in the result...

Comment: When I develop this binomial $(x^2 - 1)^n$, I get $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{2n!}{k!(2n-k)!}x^{4n-2k}(-1)^k$, there is where I'm stucked.

Comment: Sorry It's $(x^2 - 1)^{2n}$

Comment: Now coefficient of $x^{2n}$.

Comment: This happens when $k = n$, I get this, but what happen with the other values for k?

Comment: When $k = n$ we get this expression: $\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{2n!(-1)^n}{n!n!}x^{2n}$ It implies that $\frac{2n!(-1)^n2n!}{2^{2n}2n!(n!)^2}$ and I get the expected result, but there is my doubt, what happen with the other k's?

Comment: You don't care. You differentiate and then set $x=0$. Either terms are removed by differentiation, either by $x^k$ where $x=0$. Only the constant term remains.

Comment: Oh, of course I forgot that condition, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to note that the Legendre polynomials can be written as the series
$$ P_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} (-1)^k \, \binom{n}{k} \, \binom{2n - 2k}{n} \, x^{n - 2k}. $$
Note that, when $n \to 2 n + 1$, the series is
$$ P_{2n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \, \binom{2n+1}{k} \, \binom{4n-2k+2}{n} \, x^{2n - 2k +1}. $$
This series gives $P_{2n+1}(0) = 0$ as a result. When $x \to -x$ it is determined that $P_{n}(-x) = (-1)^n \, P_{n}(x)$.

Now, when $n \to 2n$ the series yields
$$ P_{2 n}(x) = \frac{1}{4^n} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \, \binom{2n}{k} \, \binom{4n - 2k}{n} \, x^{2(n-k)} $$
or
$$ P_{2 n}(x) = \frac{1}{4^n} \, \left( (-1)^n \, \binom{2n}{n} \, \binom{2n}{2n} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \, \binom{2n}{k} \, \binom{4n - 2k}{n} \, x^{2(n-k)} \right) $$
and, for $x = 0$, gives
$$ P_{2 n}(0) = \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n} \, \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n-1}} \, \frac{(2n-1)!}{n! \, (n-1)!}. $$
This is the result desired for the proposed question.

Also note that in order to show $P_{n}(\pm 1) = (\pm 1)^n$ that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} (-1)^k \, \binom{n}{k} \, \binom{2n -2k}{n} = 2^n $$
first must be obtained.